# Como faço para o item selecionado de uma Lista de Categorias seja realocado na primeira posição

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Em minha aplicação tenho uma área com vários links de categorias que é uma PartialView.

Ás categorias abaixo vem da da seguinte instrução da CategoriasController

```
var categorias = db.Categorias.ToList();
```

Calçados | Saúde e Beleza | Supermercados | Restaurantes

A **ActionResult** da PartialView codificada abaixo fica sabendo qual link que o usuário clicou, através  de um **TempData("filtroSelecionado")**.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult _CatalogoFiltroCategoria()
{
    TempData.Keep("filtroSelecionado");

    var categorias = db.Categorias.ToList();

    return PartialView(@"~/Views/Anuncios/_CatalogoFiltroCategoria.cshtml", categorias);
}
```

Como faço para que a var categorias coloque como primeira da ToList() o link selecionado.

Clico em **Restaurantes** me retorne a lista assim.

**Restaurantes** | Calçados | Saúde e Beleza | Supermercados

Clico em **Saúde e Beleza** me retorne a lista com **Saúde e Beleza** em primeiro da lista

**Saúde e Beleza** | Calçados| Supermercados | Restaurantes

Answer (score 0):

Usando `linq` voce pode usar o comando `insert` passando o index e o item. Exemplo:

Dado sua lista Saúde e Beleza | Calçados| Supermercados | Restaurantes
Imagine que você queira colocar calçados em primeiro, você faria o seguinte:

```
categorias.RemoveAt(1);
categorias.Insert(0,"Calçados");
```

o que deixaria ela assim :

Calçados| Saúde e Beleza | Supermercados | Restaurantes

Comment: Confesso que não entendi sua resposta, daria para exemplificar melhor ?

Comment: editado com mais detalhes